# Scaling HTML Canvas elements

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scale

In my main project I have lots of little canvas elements (think: sprites from a sprite map) and I need to be able to scale them before drawing them to the main canvas. Here is my basic code for this:

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var miniCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var miniCanvasContext = miniCanvas.getContext('2d');

miniCanvasContext.beginPath();
miniCanvasContext.rect(0,0,100,100);
miniCanvasContext.closePath();
miniCanvasContext.fillStyle = 'red';
miniCanvasContext.fill();

miniCanvasContext.scale(2,2);//THIS IS THE PROBLEM


ctx.drawImage(miniCanvas, 100, 100);
```

This test is up at jsfiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/041r73tg/)

Essentially, I need this red square to be increased in size by two times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawImage method has a version that lets you draw the miniCanvas with scaling:

```
// the last 2 parameters are scaled Width & scaled Height

// parameters:
// 1st: the image source
// 2nd,3rd: the upper-left part of the source to clip from
// 4th,5th: the width & height to clip from the source
// 6th,7th: the upper-left part of the canvas to draw the clipped image
// 8th,9th: the scaled width & height to draw on the canvas

ctx.drawImage(miniCanvas, 0,0,100,100, 0,0,200, 200);
```

Comment: Hey. I'm getting some odd resizing with this.http://jsfiddle.net/041r73tg/2/ even if it's 200 the shape is still oblong instead of square.

Comment: Ahh yes, you should set the miniCanvas size to the size of the sprite: miniCanvas.width=100; miniCanvas.height=100;. Alternatively, I've updated my answer to show the slightly longer version that clips the sprite from miniCanvas and draws it scales on ctx. Cheers!